# Disable Responsiveness or similar functionality for Code Review

Tags: feature-request, support, user-interface

Stack Overflow used to have 'disable responsiveness' option at the bottom of the screen, so that it was possible to get more information (i.e. the code and question) on the screen, in effect 'disabling' the right hand menu.

Is there a way to do that on Code Review?
Is it a feature that will ever be introduced?

No amount of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> ever gets more code on the screen:- (See the following screen shots)

[image]
[image]

And slightly ridiculously:

[image]

The screen is divided (on CodeReview) into three vertical areas:
Left section contains *Home* *Public* *Teams*, the central section the code and question and the right-hand side section what looks like *'tips'*. (currently I have How to Format). With the old 'disable responsiveness', the right hand section would be 'disabled' and thus the centre vertical section would gain more width,thus there'd be more writing/code/information in that central strip.  In answer to @Mast, "No that's not what I'm referring to." (not enough rep to comment)

With well formatted code it's not an issue, but sometimes program logic can be complicated and thus the indentation be large or when beginners post code sometimes their indentation can be off.
There is a scroll bar at the bottom, but I use a dark mode on my browser and the scroll bar is almost invisible. Just getting more information on the screen makes reviewing folks' code much easier, and isn't that what should be being facilitated?

I have tried searching the following topics in meta:

- "automatic text sizing"
- "disable responsiveness"
- "hot network questions"
- "menus"
- "side menus"
- "text size codereview"
- "should font size for question text and code blocks be the same"

But I have not been able to find anything on the subject.

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/9GNk8lg.png) is what the width of my screen looks like at 120%. [This](https://imgur.com/bjxmtTE.png) is at 170%. The latter uses about as much of the width as practically possible. Would that be what you want?

Comment: In your settings, you can disable the left navigation bar. That would help a lot already. You can find it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/).

Comment: @Mast. Yes that helps enormously, can the right bar be disabled? I flipped the switch below: **When you flip this switch, you will no longer see Hot Network Questions in the right sidebar on Q&A sites**, but there's still 'Related' and 'Tips'. Is it possible to get rid of the right hand menu as well ?

Comment: I tried putting **disable left navigation bar** into the codereview search bar, to see if it would bring up any info about settings, but it brought up this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Stack Overflow used to have 'disable responsiveness' option at the bottom of the screen ...
> Is there a way to do that on Code Review?

No, not that I'm aware. As far as I know, that setting was a temporary solution implemented somewhere around 2018 that could be used while they were making the [entire network responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/269301). That has been done, so the old pages are no longer maintained.

However, you can get rid of the left bar. That's the [navigation bar mentioned in the settings](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/):
[image: Hide left navigation in Preferences, under Site Settings]

As you've found yourself, there's a similar setting hiding the Hot Network Questions. But that still leaves that column in use by other components.

Most of the whitespace can be removed by zooming in, but this could depend on your browser, device or settings. For example, looking at [the answer you got your picture from](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/135309/52915), this is what I can make that specific part look like on my monitor:

[image: Same picture, less whitespace]

That's on a fairly standard 16:9 monitor.

The size is starting to look silly, but it has more space actually in use than it had. Unfortunately, that's about as good as it gets.

If you want to remove more, you'll have to go the unsupported route and dig into [userscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript). There are a number of userscripts available, written by community members, on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/). For example, [here](https://stackapps.com/search?q=hide+is%3Aq)'s a list of all questions mentioning `hide`. For example, [this script](https://stackapps.com/q/4844/32480) claims to remove some links from the Community Bulletin and [this script](https://stackapps.com/q/6430/32480) claims to remove certain sites from the Hot Network Questions. In theory it's possible to create a userscript that hides a lot more. I do not know the limitations and, again, this method is not supported. And by not supported, I mean [a lot of regulars are depending on it quite a bit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372957/269301).

Note: there are many more ways to find userscripts to your liking. For example, [Violentmonkey](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/by-site/stackexchange.com?filter_locale=0) has a page for Stack Exchange sites and GitHub has a lot of them as well.